# Copy Activity missing column in the output

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity which takes the output of a procedure and writes it to a temp CSV file. I needed to have headers in double quotation mark so after that I have a Data Flow task that takes the temp file and adds the quote all in the sink settings. Yet the output is not what is expected. It looks like the last column is missing in some of the records due to comma in the data.

Is there a way to use only copy activity but still have the column names in double quotes?

Comment: we need more details , can you give us more example data? Like source and output, which column missed.

Comment: I found the root cause. It was due to a comma in one of the columns but I don't know how to overcome it. I need to have everything separated by comma and in double quotation marks including the header

Comment: Hi @Joanna, if you set comma as the delimiter,  data factory will consider the first row as the schema according the delimiter numbers.  If your data value which contains the  comma,  then you will miss the column. And just for now in Data Factory, we can't solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we set the column delimiter, data factory will consider the first row as the schema according the delimiter number. If your data which has the value which same with the column delimiter, then you will miss some columns.

Just for now in Data Factory, we can't solve it. The only way is that please se the different column delimiter, for example the '|':
[image]
Output example:

[image]

And we also can't make the header wrapped by double quote for the output .csv file. It's not supported in Data Factory.

HTH.

Comment: I found a workaround for the header double quote. I changed the column name to contain the quotation mark and it works.